# changing background data state in Android

Tags: android, security, settings, widget

Allow me to start with a little rant: While Background Data is enabled on my Galaxy S (Froyo) the battery completely drains in just a few hours! I really cant figure out why when both my exchange and gmail accounts are set to push. In any case, this leads to the need to turn BG Data off to conserve my battery and turn it on mainly for browsing the marketplace.
I dont understand why the Market app cant simply turn the thing on when I open the app and not bother me about it and I really dont get why everytime I turn BG Data off I get a dialog telling me it will save me battery, I know that! thats why im turning if off!!! eurghhhh...

With that out of the way, I wanted to write a little widget that will allow me to turn Background Data on and off whenever I want without going through the menus and seeing that annoying dialog.
Then I found out that this setting is one of the "secured settings" which apps cant change.

What I wanted to ask, is whether there is any way to change a secure setting in Android through code? Has anyone found a way around this? Or do we just have to live with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have lots of widgets? Check how often then are updating. The network data connection is probably constantly active if they are updating every few minutes as it doesn't disconnect instantly. I'd suggest not syncing any quicker than every 15 minutes.

Comment: Just use the battery usage display to find out which app is drinking your milkshake.

Comment: Thats what I initially thought but when I removed all widgets and even turned off "Auto-sync" the battery dies almost just quickly... For some reason (at least on my Galaxy S) BG Data simply sucks all the juice out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I wanted to ask, is whether there is any way to change a secure setting in Android through code?

Only by modifying the firmware.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that would be the answer but wanted to be sure I wasnt missing anything.